# Good way (and/or platform-independent place) to cache data from web

Tags: python, caching, html

My pygtk program is an editor for XML-based documents which reference other documents, possibly online, that may in turn reference further documents.

When I load a file, the references are resolved and the documents loaded (already asynchronously). However, this process repeats every time I start the editor, so I want some local caching to save bandwidth and time for both the user and the server hosting the referenced documents.

Are there any typical ways this is done? My idea so far would be:

- Get a path to a cache directory somehow (platform-independent)

  - Any ideas?
- Put a file named `md5(url)` there.
- If there is a cache file already existing and it's not older than `$cache_policy_age` take it, otherwise use HTTP (can `urllib` do that?) to check if it has been modified since it was downloaded.

Comment: It would actually be nice to at least comment why you downvote this question.

Comment: I upvoted - even if the implementation described in the question is a bad idea (not saying it is!) it's a perfectly well formed question. I don't understand why it's been voted down either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personnaly I use [os.path.expanduser](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to find a good place for caches, it's quite common in unix environnement where most of the current user's config/cache is saved under his home directory, the use of a directory name starting with a dot, making an "hidden" directory.

I would do something like :

```
directory = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), ".my_cache")
```

As for the modification date of the distant file you can use `urlib` :

```
import urllib
u = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
u.info().get("last-modified")
```

However you should check that your HTTP server provides the last-modified HTTP header and that it is a coherent value ! (This is not always the case)

Comment: This was a good answer 11 years ago, but today another good (perhaps better) way is to use `pathlib`:

`directory = Path.home() / ".my_cache"`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html